# Присваивание уникального значения атрибута каждому элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно из переданного (по id) блока найти все картинки и каждой присвоить уникальное значение атрибута.

Сейчас сделано так:

```
$("#detailArt").find("a:has(img)").attr('data-fancybox', Math.random());
```

Но, к сожалению, данная конструкция присваивает всем картинкам одинаковое число, то есть обращается к функции `Math.random()` только один раз для всех найденных элементов.
Как это исправить? Нужны уникальные значения для каждого элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$("#detailArt").find("a:has(img)").each(function() {
   $(this).attr('data-fancybox', Math.random());
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: ну и добавить вместо Math.random(): `'img_' + Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10,10))`

Answer (score 1):

[Один из вариантов](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) передаваемых параметров в функцию `attr` - это название атрибута и функция, возвращающая значение данного атрибута для конкретного элемента

При использовании такого варианта получается так:

```
$("#detailArt").find("a:has(img)").attr("data-fancybox", function() { return Math.random(); });
```

В более современном оформлении:

```
$("#detailArt").find("a:has(img)").attr("data-fancybox", () => Math.random());
```

И, наконец, вариант не очень правильный*, но ещё более короткий:

```
$("#detailArt").find("a:has(img)").attr("data-fancybox", Math.random);
```

*** По-хорошему, в `Math.random` не должны передаваться параметры